# Creating Rectangle using Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

As someone new to pygame, I have searched the web for how to create a rectangle. I then used that code, but when run it just showed a blank screen. No error codes showed, but the code didn't run like I thought it would. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS

pygame.init

#window variables
WindowHeight = 480
WindowWidth = 640


surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WindowWidth,WindowHeight))
surface.fill((255,255,255))


pygame.draw.rect(surface,(100,0,155),(0,0,100,100))




while True:
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():
        if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

Comment: You're not *calling* `pygame.init`.

Comment: Does the window show

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty, but to write a good pygame code start from this:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *


WindowHeight = 480
WindowWidth = 640

def main():
    pygame.init()

    DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((WindowWidth,WindowHeight),0,32)

    WHITE=(255,255,255)
    blue=(0,0,255)

    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,blue,(200,150,100,50))

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

put everything in the `main` function, `init` pygame and `update` the display.

This creates a simple window that is white. Within the window will be a blue rectangle. Look up [pygame.org](https://www.pygame.org/) for more info